# WCF class not exposed to application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a class `CibilResponse`  which in turn has properties that are of type class TUEF. As per my understanding, since I have included `CibilEnquiry` in the interface in wcf , it is available to my application but shouldnt TUEF be also available since `CibilEnquiry` class uses `TUEF`?

**ICIBIL.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICIBIL
{

    [OperationContract]
    string InsertCibil(CibilResponse cibilResponse);


    [OperationContract]
    string GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiry testObj);


}

[DataContract]
public class CibilResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ResponseString { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Business { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MkrId { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class CibilEnquiry
{
    [DataMember]
    public TUEF Tuef { get; set; }   

    public CibilEnquiry()
    {
        this.Tuef = new TUEF();
    }

}


    [DataContract]
    public class TUEF
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SegmentTag { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MemberReferenceNumber { get; set; }        

    }
```

**Appication :**

```
CibilWcfService.CIBIL obj = new CibilWcfService.CIBIL();
    CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry CibilEnquiryEnq = new CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry();
    Tuef objtuef=new Tuef();//Tuef not found.. are you missing an assembly reference error
    objtuef.Version="123";
CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef=objtuef;
   string res = obj.GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiryEnq);
```

Comment: Did you mark TUEF calss with [DataContract] and properties with [DataMember] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef = new CibilWcfService.Tuef()`

Your code will be

```
    CibilWcfService.CIBIL obj = new CibilWcfService.CIBIL();
    CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry CibilEnquiryEnq = new CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry();
    CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef objtuef=new CibilWcfService.Tuef();//Tuef not found.. are you missing an assembly reference error
    objtuef.Version="123";
    string res = obj.GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiryEnq);
```

Comment: My friend  I am not getting `Tuef`. It is not available.