# Alternate way to initialize class property which is of type class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, class, oop

I have a CibilResponse Class that has properties that are of class type (TUEF class).

**ICIBIL.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICIBIL
{    
    [OperationContract]
    string InsertCibil(CibilResponse cibilResponse);    
    [OperationContract]
    string GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiry testObj);   
}

[DataContract]
public class CibilResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ResponseString { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Business { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MkrId { get; set; }
}    

[DataContract]
public class CibilEnquiry
{
    [DataMember]
    public TUEF Tuef { get; set; }              
}    

[DataContract]
public class TUEF
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SegmentTag { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MemberReferenceNumber { get; set; }        
}
```

**Application:**

```
CibilWcfService.CIBIL obj = new CibilWcfService.CIBIL();
CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry CibilEnquiryEnq = new CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry();
CibilWcfService.TUEF objtuef = new CibilWcfService.TUEF();
objtuef.Version = "123";
CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef = objtuef;
string res = obj.GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiryEnq);
```

As you can see I have to create a individual objects of various classes (object `objtuef` of class `TUEF` in this case) and then assign it to object `CibilEnquiryEnq` of `CibilEnquiry` class.

It can be very tedious if there are numerous members of type class in CibilResponse.  What is the better way to initialize class members?

I was thinking of using constructor in CibilResponse Class and assigning values as `CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef.Version = "123";`  but it didnt seem to work it gave me null reference error. I still had to create an object of TUEF in my application.

```
public CibilEnquiry()
{
    this.Tuef = new TUEF();
}
```

- **UPDATE:**

**Application:**

```
CibilWcfService.CIBIL obj = new CibilWcfService.CIBIL();
                CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry CibilEnquiryEnq = new CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry();
            CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef.Version = "1111";//null reference error

            string res = obj.GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiryEnq);
```

**WCF ICIBIL.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICIBIL
{

    [OperationContract]
    string InsertCibil(CibilResponse cibilResponse);

    [OperationContract]
    string TestInsert(string testObj);

    [OperationContract]
    string GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiry testObj);

}

[DataContract]
public class CibilEnquiry
{
    [DataMember]
    public TUEF Tuef { get; set; }
    public CibilEnquiry()
    {
        this.Tuef = new TUEF();
        //this.Tuef = new TUEF() { SegmentTag = "", Version = ""};
    }

}


 [DataContract]
    public class TUEF
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SegmentTag { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MemberReferenceNumber { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Why don't you told community users to build your application :P .. Here is your previous question regarding this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749714/wcf-class-not-exposed-to-application

Comment: @MoumitMondal not a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

The best way to initialize them in constructor, which you already suggested here.

Create a parametric constructor, and pass those parameters to your instance:

```
public CibilEnquiry(string segmentTag, string version, string memberReferenceNumber)
{
    this.Tuef = new TUEF()
    {
        SegmentTag = segmentTag, 
        Version = version, 
        MemberReferenceNumber = memberReferenceNumber
    };
    //initialize all of your class properties here
    //simply it is the purpose of constructor to properly initialize the instance
}
```

If you don't want to pass values through constructor, just initialize the instance in there and assign the values later:

```
public class CibilEnquiry
{
    public CibilEnquiry()
    {
        this.Tuef = new TUEF();
    }

    public TUEF Tuef { get; set; }
}
```

Instantiating the class:

```
CibilEnquiry enquiry = new CibilEnquiry();
enquiry.Tuef.Version = "123";
```

Comment: Is it possible to create an instance of CibilEnquiry without passing any values like : `CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry CibilEnquiryEnq = new CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry();`  (may be set members to default values as null)

and then setting the values as : `CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef.Version = "123";`

Comment: Yes it is possible, you don't even need to set `null` values. They will already be null if you don't assign anything to them.

Comment: How? I added this constructor : `public CibilEnquiry()
    {        
        this.Tuef = new TUEF() { SegmentTag = "", Version = ""};
    }`
But still i am getting null reference error at `CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef.Version = "123";`

Comment: I saw your updated answer and I had tried exactly same thing ` this.Tuef = new TUEF();` moments ago. But still it did not solve null reference error.

Comment: It should work, I also tested it its all working fine. May be you're missing something. Can you add the updated class code and how you're instantiating it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95307/discussion-between-shaharyar-and-arbaaz).

Comment: the Tuef is null
in `CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef.Version` CibilEnquiryEnq is present , Tuef is null